# Как передать атрибут data-raw="числовое значение" из select option в метод $.post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как разобрать тэг option внутри select чтобы получить значение data-raw="1" и передать его в метод POST. Сложности возникают из-за того что тэг находится внутри другого тэга. Как видно по скриншоту, данный тэг (option) содержит нужную информацию, трудность возникает только в том как получить значение data атрибута в нем

```
var els1=document.getElementsByClassName('mult');
var zet1=[];
els1=[].slice.call(els1);
var flag1=1;

els1.forEach(function(el1,i){
    el1.addEventListener('click',function(event){
        if(flag1){ 
        var array = [" ", "Замечание", "согласовано", "не согласовано"];
        var arr=["0", " ", "2", "1"]; //массив элементов которые передается в метод $.post из тэга option
            var select;
            select=document.createElement('select');
            select.name=this.dataset.name;
            select.dataset.id=this.dataset.id;
            select.type='text';
            var val=this.innerHTML;
            select.value=this.innerHTML;
            this.dataset.old=this.innerHTML;
            this.innerHTML='';
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
                option.setAttribute("data-name", arr[i]);
                option.text = array[i];
                select.appendChild(option);
            }
            select=this.appendChild(select);
            $(select).focus();
            select.addEventListener('blur', function(){
                send1(this);    
            });
            select.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
                if(event.keyCode=='27'){
                    this.parentElement.innerHTML=this.parentElement.dataset.old;
                    flag1=1;
                }
                if(event.keyCode=='13'){
                    send1(this);
                    flag1=1;
                }
            })
            flag1=0;
        } 
    });
});







function send1(el1){
    if(el1.parentElement.dataset.old!=el1.value){
    el1.parentElement.dataset.new=el1.value;
    id=el1.dataset.id;
    name=el1.name;
    val=el1.value;
    $.post( "/project/tabl.php", { name: name, id: id, value: val, last:"mult", } );
}
    val=el1.value;
    el1.parentElement.innerHTML=val;
    flag1=1;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в чем этот тайный смысл писать все на чистом js, и только для `post` использовать `jquery`?

Comment: @teran, у меня при клике создается select option в котором пользователь выбирает значение и оно сохраняется в бд (пользователю не нужно перезугражать страницу чтобы увидеть что значение поменялось). Я просто запарился не много, и не могу получить значения атрибута data-raw на Js внутри тэга select option

Answer (score 1):

Таким оброзом:
Jquery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($('option:selected').attr('data-raw'));
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].options[document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-raw'));
```